# converting jquery hide/fade/delay/animation to pure js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove the jquery dependency from my code and came across a few lines I have no idea how to replicate in js.

I know I can use setTimeout() in place of delay, css transitions for the fading, and css for the hide... just not sure how to go about it and haven't been able to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

**part in question that needs converted to plain js :**

```
//loop that actually does the work
(function loopBg(){     
    $topSlide.hide().css({'background' : 'transparent url('+images[++c%n][0]+') '+images[c%n][1]}).delay(6000).fadeTo(2000, 1, function(){
        $bottomSlide.css({'background' : 'transparent url('+images[c%n][0]+') '+images[c%n][1]}); 
        loopBg();
    });
}());
```

**entire original jquery code :**

```
//2nd position is where it starts from
var images = [
    ['/assets/img/sliders/6-sm.jpg', 'no-repeat scroll center bottom / cover'],
    ['/assets/img/sliders/9-sm.jpg', 'no-repeat scroll center bottom / cover'],
    ['/assets/img/sliders/2-sm.jpg', 'no-repeat scroll center bottom / cover'],
];

var $bottomSlide = $('#intro-anim .slider-bottom'),
    $topSlide = $('#intro-anim .slider-top'),
    n = images.length,
    c = 0; // loop counter

// preload array of images
for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
    var tImg = new Image();
    tImg.src = images[i][0];
}

$bottomSlide.css({
    'background' : 'transparent url('+images[++c%n][0]+') '+images[c%n][1]
}); 

//loop that actually does the work
(function loopBg(){     
    $topSlide.hide().css({'background' : 'transparent url('+images[++c%n][0]+') '+images[c%n][1]}).delay(6000).fadeTo(2000, 1, function(){
        $bottomSlide.css({'background' : 'transparent url('+images[c%n][0]+') '+images[c%n][1]}); 
        loopBg();
    });
}());
```

**my conversion minus the section in question :**

```
//2nd position is where it starts from
const images = [
    ['/assets/img/sliders/6-sm.jpg', 'no-repeat scroll center bottom / cover'],
    ['/assets/img/sliders/9-sm.jpg', 'no-repeat scroll center bottom / cover'],
    ['/assets/img/sliders/2-sm.jpg', 'no-repeat scroll center bottom / cover'],
];

const bottomSlide = document.querySelector('#intro-anim .slider-bottom'),
    topSlide = document.querySelector('#intro-anim .slider-top');

let n = images.length,
    c = 0; //loop counter

//preload array of images
for(let i=0; i<n; i++){
    let tImg = new Image();
    tImg.src = images[i][0];
}

bottomSlide.setAttribute('style', 'background: transparent url('+images[++c%n][0]+') '+images[c%n][1]);

//loop that actually does the work
//still needs converted
//(function loopBg(){       
//  $topSlide.hide().css({'background' : 'transparent url('+images[++c%n][0]+') '+images[c%n][1]}).delay(6000).fadeTo(2000, 1, function(){
//      $bottomSlide.css({'background' : 'transparent url('+images[c%n][0]+') '+images[c%n][1]}); 
//      loopBg();
//  });
//}());
```

Comment: My advice: It would be a better use of your time figuring out how to convert your  jquery animations into CSS 3 transitions / animations. Now that this is possible in CSS, you should take advantage

Comment: That is exactly what I said I'd like to do in my post and which I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Your question is asking how to convert the jQuery to plain JS, not convert the jQuery to CSS. You may want to update the question to be clearer if that's your actual goal

Comment: I'm very well aware of that.  Where are you confused in my post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of hacky, but replicates the same behavior as before which is what I wanted.  I'll look into ways to make this cleaner.

The gist is the top slider changes its image and fades in.  After fade in the bottom slider changes to the same image while the top goes back to opacity 0 (keeping the same image visible).  Repeats every 6 seconds going to the next image in the array.

```
//2nd position is where it starts from
const images = [
    ['/assets/img/sliders/6-sm.jpg', 'no-repeat scroll center bottom / cover'],
    ['/assets/img/sliders/9-sm.jpg', 'no-repeat scroll center bottom / cover'],
    ['/assets/img/sliders/2-sm.jpg', 'no-repeat scroll center bottom / cover'],
];

const bottomSlide = document.querySelector('#intro-anim .slider-bottom'),
    topSlide = document.querySelector('#intro-anim .slider-top');

let n = images.length,
    c = 0; //loop counter

//preload array of images
for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
    var tImg = new Image();
    tImg.src = images[i][0];
}

bottomSlide.style.background = 'transparent url('+images[++c%n][0]+') '+images[c%n][1];
topSlide.style.opacity = '0';

//loop that actually does the work
(function loopBg(){
    
    setTimeout(function() {
    
        topSlide.style.background = 'transparent url('+images[++c%n][0]+') '+images[c%n][1];
        topSlide.style.opacity = '1';
        
        setTimeout(function() {
            bottomSlide.style.background = 'transparent url('+images[c%n][0]+') '+images[c%n][1];
            topSlide.style.opacity = '0';
        }, 3000); //css transition for '#intro-anim .slider-top' is 2 seconds so do 3 to be safe and let it finish (6s is the total between slides) 
        
        loopBg();
    }, 6000);       

}());
```

**css with added transition for 2s :**

```
#intro-anim .slider-top,
#intro-anim .slider-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#intro-anim .slider-top {
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}
```